# Push a newly created file into git repository

Tags: linux, git, push

I have created a git repository of a linux directory and pushed all files into it. I have recently moved a new file into that linux directory and now want to push this new file into its git repository. I am trying to do so by typing

```
 git push origin master
```

in the command line but I am getting the errors:

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Does anyone know how to push a new file into an existing git repo of the folder in which the file is present? I am new to git so would appreciate suggestions.

Comment: You have a local repo only or a remote one also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is already in the git repo you have created, adding and committing are enough: no need to push.

```
myrepo      <== "I have created a git repository of a linux directory"
  .git           (the .git folder is the git repo referential)
  myNewfile <== "I have recently moved a new file into that linux directory"
```

[image: http://training-course-material.com/images/thumb/8/8d/Git-commit-a2.png/250px-Git-commit-a2.png]

Ie. there is no remote 'origin' to push to for a local git repo.

The chapter "[Git Basics - Recording Changes to the Repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository)" is the good place to start.

```
git add myNewFile
git commit -m "Add a new file"
```

Comment: I see! So do I need to do: git commit -m "somemessage" and git add "filename" to push the new file that I added in the folder?

Comment: @zsha no: git add, and then git commit. See more at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a wrong understanding about `git push` command, please read the following figure, which will give you a more clean concept.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Validate if you have the repository branch (on which you are working) checkedout.
2. Make sure you pull the updates first
3. Do 'git add newfileNameWithPath' and commit before you push it.